# collapsed menu as default wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu

hello I am trying to collapse the menu categories on the mobile version of my website through javascript. I have many menu options so on mobile with them all expanded this is not user friendly...is there a script I can use that will make the menu only expand sub-cats when touched? 
my site is www.cocvids.com (this is clash of clans and is SFW)

Comment: By default, in wordpress you can add a parent to a page, this will make its children and the parent will be a subcat.

Please check wordpress codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Comment: Yes, I have no issue making subcats..the issue is that all of the subcat menu items are auto expanded in mobile view